# 'Length of values does not match length of index' on a groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, multi-index

I am having a strange bug with a pandas groupby in one of my databricks notebook.

Data are confidential, so this is a dummy **illustration** of my bug (*the dataframe df is actually the result from a merge of two other dataframe*).

If you want to reproduce the dataframe :

```
data = {'group1':  ['a', 'b','a','a','a'],
        'group2': ['f', 'f', 'f' , 'f', 'f'],
         'aggregate': ['1', '2','3','4','5'],}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['group1','group2','aggregate'])
```

At this stage , the dataframe df is displayed correctly. Now i am doing a groupby :

```
agg = df.groupby(['group2', 'group1'],  as_index=False).agg({'aggregate':', '.join})
```

I should be getting this :

[image]

But I am getting this :

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Only ways "to make it work" is :

**Fix 1 :**
agg = df.groupby(['group2', 'group1'],  as_index=True).agg({'aggregate':', '.join}).reset_index()

And i am getting this :

[image: group2 group1 aggregate 0 f a 1, 3, 4, 5 1 f b 2 2 f NaN]

**Fix 2** :
After the initial merge, "reset the dataframe", to have a new fresh one.
This works perfectly but is not really nice.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(drift.to_dict())
```

Is my data somehow corrupted ? How ?

Any level of feedback would be much appreciated (whether you know the the reason of the bug - which would be great! - or not), just so that I understand a bit better what could be happening behind the scenes.

Very much looking forward any suggestion or opinion here. Thank you !

Comment: Was the issue because of the Pandas version? Did my answer help you fix the issue?

Answer (score 5):

Pandas throws that error when one of the "`groupby` columns" has the `category` type.

A workaround could be calling `astype` and choosing a literal, e.g. `string`:

```py
df = df.astype({'group1': 'string', 'group2': 'string'})
```

As of March 2023 it is [still an unresolved bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/36698)

BTW [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75688904/81444) has probably the same error

Comment: A better solution is provided in the github issue if you want to keep the categorical format after the groupby: use `as_index=True` and after the `agg` use `reset_index(names=['list', 'of', 'column', 'names'])`

Answer (score 1):

I tested the same code and I got the expected result:
[image]

I tested in Google Colab. Maybe the issue is your Pandas's version. I tested your code with `pandas: 1.1.5`